# matplotlib multiple line annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to show a **multiple-line** annotation in matplotlib?

This is a single line annotation:

```
ax.annotate('line1', xy=(xi,yi),  xycoords='data',
                    xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")
                    )
```

This is what I need to do (this was edited graphically):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was as simple as adding "\n" at the end of a line :

'line1 **\n** line2 **\n** line3"

```
ax.annotate('line1 \n line2', xy=(timeNow, y),  xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-50, 30), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"),
            verticalalignment='center', 
            horizontalalignment='center'
            )
```